# Seeking a way to count or strip leading spaces of a string in pure POSIX shell

Tags: sh

I maintain a little TAP consumer called "tapview". Its main distinguishing feature is that it's written in pure POSIX shell with no external dependencies, unless you count expr(1). I deliberately have not used any bashisms; the goal is to be as portable and lightweight as possible.

Recently one of my users filed an issue about tapview being slow relative to a functionally similar Python client, and identified repeated calls to expr(1) as the culprit. I eliminated most of them for a very susbstantial speedup, almost 10x. There's just one left on the critical path.

I'm looking for a pure-POSIX shell recipe (no process spawns, no bashisms) that will count leading spaces in a string.  Alternatively, being able to strip leading (but not trailing) spaces would suffice.

Comment: What about `String='  some text '; LdSpc="${String%%[! ]*}"; echo "${#LdSpc}"` for counting?  And `"${String#$LdSpc}"` to have leading spaces stripped out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a string in var `x`,

Count:

```bash
leading_spaces="${x%%[! ]*}"
leading_spaces_count=${#leading_spaces}
```

Strip:

```bash
leading_spaces="${x%%[! ]*}"
stripped="${x#$leading_spaces}"
```